# How do I drop all rows with a non numeric value for ColB in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, numeric

I would like to drop all of the rows thatt contains values that are not numeric in Col2. I am not sure how to do this in Sql.

```
Col1    Col2  Col3

word1   123    Code
word2   124    Code
word3   tttt   code

Drop  * row from db.Table 
where col2 Value is not numeric;
```

I want the table to look like this:

```
Col1    Col2  Col3

word1   123    Code
word2   124    Code
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: There's no Column B in your table, did you mean `Col2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ANSI-standard SQL, you can get quite close with something like:

```
delete from t
    where substring(col2, 1, 1) between '0' and '9';
```

Most databases support more refined methods for such comparisons.  For instance, in SQL Server you can do:

```
delete from t
    where try_convert(int, col2) is null;
```

In Oracle:

```
delete from t
    where regexp_like(col2, '[^0-9]');
```

In MySQL:

```
delete from t
    where col2 regexp '[^0-9]';
```

Comment: Your conditions are backwards. She wants to keep numeric values, drop non-numeric ones.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, SQL's `try_convert()` is SQL2012+.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `regexp` keyword with `[^0-9]+`

`[^0-9]+` will get contain non-number value.

```
delete from t
where col2 regexp '[^0-9]+';
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3717d/1

Comment: No need for `+`. You only need to match one non-numeric character.

Comment: `+` or `.` both are Ok :)

Comment: When I run this all of the ones that include numeric values get deleted and all the ones that contain characters get deleted. The column is of type text. When I changed the column to int the same thing happened.

Comment: @JessicaWarren It worked in sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b4bf5/1
make sure the regex string is `[^0-9]+`

Comment: It also works if the regex is `[^0-9]` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ab8c12/1

Comment: @Barmar I had the ^ on the wrong side of the brackets. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex, and making your column `TEXT` datatype can cause all sorts of storage and I/O issues.

Just use

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE concat('',coalesce(col2,1) * 1) <> coalesce(col2,0) ;
```

==============================================================

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10a3aa/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Initial Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1( col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50) );

INSERT INTO t1 (col1,col2,col3) 
SELECT 'word1','123','Code' UNION ALL
SELECT 'word2','124','Code' UNION ALL
SELECT 'word3','tttt','Code' UNION ALL
SELECT 'word4','5ttt','Code' UNION ALL
SELECT 'word5','ttt5','Code'
;

CREATE TABLE t1_before ( col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50) );
INSERT INTO t1_before (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT *
FROM t1 ;
```

**BEFORE DELETE**:

```
SELECT * FROM t1_before 

|  col1 | col2 | col3 |
|-------|------|------|
| word1 |  123 | Code |
| word2 |  124 | Code |
| word3 | tttt | Code |
| word4 | 5ttt | Code |
| word5 | ttt5 | Code |
```

**DELETE STATEMENT**

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE concat('',coalesce(col2,1) * 1) <> coalesce(col2,0) ;
```

**AFTER DELETE**:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 


|  col1 | col2 | col3 |
|-------|------|------|
| word1 |  123 | Code |
| word2 |  124 | Code |
```

EDIT: I changed my `DELETE` statement to account for `NULL` values in `Col2`.